# Problems with casting and sqrt() in C

Tags: c, types

This program finds the distance between two points on a plane capable of floating points. But what I can't figure out (which might be due to my ignorance) is the problem with computing the `dist` variable. It is set to a Pythagorean equation that returns what should be the distance. All other variables in the system are correct.

What I am mostly having a problem though is an obvious bug with the `sqrt()` in it's use in this example. For example, if I were to make `xdist = 1` with everything else set to 0, the distance should be 1. However, what is printed as `dist` is exactly 1072693248. I only found [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434640/printf-displays-something-weird) related to this number. But what was mentioned in the answers was that only the wrong use of `%d` in `printf` caused that issue, but I see (to what I know) there isn't a problem with `printf` and formatting anywhere in the program. What is the solution to get the correct value?

```
double distance(xdist, ydist)
{
    return sqrtf(pow(xdist, 2.0) + pow(ydist, 2.0));
}

int main()
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;

    double xdist, ydist, dist;

    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
            printf("%d: Enter an x and y coordinate:\n", i);
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    scanf("%lf", &x1);
                    scanf("%lf", &y1);
                    continue;
                case 2:
                    scanf("%lf", &x2);
                    scanf("%lf", &y2);
                    continue;
            }
    }

    xdist = fabs(x2 - x1);
    ydist = fabs(y2 - y1);

    dist = distance(xdist, ydist);

    printf("\nxdist = %.2f, ydist = %.2f\n", xdist, ydist);
    printf("The distance between coordinates \n(%.2f, %.2f) to (%.2f, %.2f) \nis %.2f.", x1, y1, x2, y2, dist);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double distance(xdist, ydist)` ... call me ignorant about C programming, but don't you need to declare the types of `xdist` and `ydist`?

Comment: Also, you don't need to take the absolute value of the difference between the x and y ordinates, as squaring loses the sign anyway (the codomain of y=x^2 where x is real rather than complex, is y >= 0).

Comment: 1) makes more sense to use `sqrt()` than `sqrtf()` in `double distance(xdist, ydist) { return sqrtf(pow(xdist, 2.0) + pow(ydist, 2.0));}`  2) Simplify `double distance(double xdist, double ydist)
{
    return hypot(xdist, ydist);
}`

Comment: I used a lot of the suggestions with this question and it's combinations but I still can't find it to work. I think it might have something to do with my compiler. I tried it at school today and it worked flawlessly (the only thing changed was the distance() arguments set to their intended data type).

Answer (score 4):

Type of arguments are not defined in distance function so it will be default int. you have to define their type double

```
 double distance(double xdist, double ydist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. Problems with the scanf() caused some weird printing of floats I think. I had switched "%lf" to "%f" and then to "%lf" again. But within that I don't know what fixed it exactly. The final code is:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double distance(double xdist, double ydist)
{
    return hypot(xdist, ydist);
}

int main()
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;

    double xdist, ydist, dist;

    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
            printf("%d: Enter an x and y coordinate:\n", i);
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    scanf("%lf", &x1);
                    scanf("%lf", &y1);
                    continue;
                case 2:
                    scanf("%lf", &x2);
                    scanf("%lf", &y2);
                    continue;
            }
    }

    xdist = x2 - x1;
    ydist = y2 - y1;

    dist = distance(xdist, ydist);

    printf("\nxdist = %.2f, ydist = %.2f\n", xdist, ydist);
    printf("The distance between coordinates \n(%.2f, %.2f) to (%.2f, %.2f) \nis %.2f.", x1, y1, x2, y2, dist);

    return 0;
}
```

But if I were to guess, what fixed this was simplified use of hypot(), removal of fabs() to find the ydist and xdist, and the distance() function taking double parameters.