# How to interpret the memory of a float allocated in an int to simulate a multiplication?

Tags: c++, c, unions

With the data type "union", I can convert a float to an int. Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int float_as_int(float f)
{
    union { int i; float f; } u;
    u.f = f;
    return u.i;
}

int main() {
    float f = 1.01;
    printf("float = %f\n", f);
    printf("int   = %d\n", float_as_int(f));
    system("pause");
}
```

The result of this code is:

```
float = 1.010000
int   = 1065437102
```

However, from this value **"1065437102"** how can I get the information about the float it represents.
For example: The 32-bit number which it stores and position the "point" (fixed point on the base 2)?

**EDIT:** The answer to that question was asked here -> [How to get the sign, mantissa and exponent of a floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685181/how-to-get-the-sign-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number)

Comment: `float` isn't a fixed point format, that's your problem.

Comment: I think the float format used to be considered hw dependent, and non-portable.  There are still multiple standards for memory layout.  I think the union approach results in undefined behaviour.  Recommend you use available conversion.  Be sure to measure your performance, and I doubt you can do better than what is available from your tools.  Good luck.

Comment: It's architecture-dependent, but in all likelihood it's [IEEE 754 single-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). What architecture are you interested in?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in C in a clean, portable way. For platform and compiler dependent hacks, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685181/how-to-get-the-sign-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910115/how-to-represent-float-number-in-memory-in-c etc.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, actually I need to study it better.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I intended to compile the same code for Linux and Windows x64.

Comment: BTW, your code won't work on Linux, because `system("pause")` won't work on Linux

Comment: @dxiv `frexp()`, mentioned in the answers to some of those questions, is a portable solution.

Comment: @duskwuff Correct, but that's C++ only. My comment referred to C specifically.

Comment: @dxiv No, `frexp()` doesn't require C++. It's also available in C.

Comment: @duskwuff I stand corrected. It looks like `frexp` has always been in ISO C and the `float` overload was standardized in C99. Thank you for the followup.

Comment: `int` is not guaranteed to have 32 bits. `float` neither. Both are not guaranteed to have same endianess.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get this information because I want to convert floating point to fixed point as quickly as possible.

Just use C casts, e.g. `(int)f` is compiled to *fast* code doing the conversion. If you think of fixed point numbers (which C99 don't have natively) you could do e.g.

```
int percent = (int)(f*100.0);
```

If you want to understand the actual machine representation of [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), it is implementation (that is [processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) specific. Read about [IEEE floating points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) (most processors are using them) & [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Perhaps you want standard rounding functions, e.g. [round](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round), or decomposing functions like [frexp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/frexp).

BTW, I don't think that the C standard guarantees that `int` and `float` have the same size and alignment, so your `union` trick is implementation specific (it does however "work" on x86_64/Linux systems).