# How to distinguish a negative binary number?

Tags: c, binary

Suppose I am dealing with 4 bit operations. So if I encounter an binary digit say

```
1111
```

then what should I infer ? Is it -1 or 15 ?

Comment: It depends on the format, but if it's 2s complement then it's -1. (If it's 1's complement it would be -0, if it's sign + magnitude then it's -7, and if it's offset binary then it's +7).

Comment: It depends on the *context*. Even the mighty CPU does not know its sign: you would use the appropriate instructions.

Comment: Since your question is about C, you don't just have a sequence of binary digits. You probably have a *value* stored in an *object* of some specific *type*. (And that object is bigger than 4 bits, unless it's a bit-field.) If you can explain in exactly what form you have those 4 bits, the question is likely to answer itself. As it is, you say nothing about C in your question. Can you update your question to show us the C code you're using?

Comment: @PaulR if it is unsigned it is +15. And...if it is weird encoding it can be anything!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: true, but I think the OP is talking about signed values (see title).

Comment: There is a _[discussion here on interpretation of bits in storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910115/how-to-represent-float-number-in-memory-in-c/6911412#6911412)_ for floating points that may shed some light on some of the dependencies that must be considered to accurately answer your question.

Comment: @PaulR that could be an unsigned so that the answer is "it is not a negative binary number".

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: strictly speaking you may be correct. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"That depends".

The bits are (in this case) encoding a number, but you have to know which kind of number (signed or unsigned, integer, fixed-point or float) in order to interpret the encoded bits.

If the number is supposed to be signed in two's complement, then the proper interpretation is -1, if it's unsigned then it's 15.

It's not possible to decide from those four bits alone, it's simply not enough information.

This of course is true for a "full-sized" value too, it could be an `int` or an `unsigned int` and you have to know that in order to correctly interpret the bits.

*Update:* If you *know* that your number is supposed to be signed, the easiest way to deal with it (assuming C, which generally doesn't have a signed 4-bit integer type) is to *sign-extend* it into a usable form.

Sign-extending merely involves taking the most significant bit of the fewer-bits number, and repeating it to the left up to (and including) the most significant bit of the target one.

So in your case, you have `0xf`, whose top bit is 1. Extending to an `int8_t`, we get:

```
const int8_t number = 0xff;
```

Which is -1.

There is no built-in way to do this sign-extension from an arbitrary few-bits number, since C can't natively deal with those.

Here's a naive approach:

```
// Sign-extend a n-bit number into 32 bits.
int32_t extend(uint32_t bits, size_t n)
{
  const bool top = bits & ((uint32_t) 1 << (n - 1));
  if (top)
  {
    for (size_t i = n; i < 32; ++i)
      bits |= 1 << i;
  }
  return bits;
}
```

If you call the above with your number:

```
printf("%d\n", (int) extend(0xf, 4));
```

it prints `-1`.

Comment: @ryyker No, the number width doesn't matter, it's equally hard if you say "I'm dealing with 2-bit numbers, what is `11`?" or "I'm dealing with 16-bit numbers, what is `1111111111111111`?". I don't understand your second quote-looking text.