# How does double 5.2 is represented in a binary file?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, ieee-754

For example the given program

```
FILE *f = fopen("test.txt","w");
double d = 5.2;
fwrite(&d, sizeof(typeof(d)), 1, f);
fclose(f);
```

when U use `xxd` to view the content I get

```
//binary
0000000: 11001101 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100  ......
0000006: 00010100 01000000                                      .@
//hex
0000000: cdcc cccc cccc 1440                      .......@
```

but I found [How to represent FLOAT number in memory in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910115) that it should look like

```
0 10000001 01001100110011001100110
```

so I am not sure if its the same binary in memory and file or I am completely wrong. How can i determine the float value from given example?

Comment: Yes, you can write the value to a file and view it. But part of the problem is that you're confusing `float` and `double`. Both are floating point values. But `float` is typically 32 bits whereas `double` is 64 bits. And they have different encodings. So try changing `double d = 5.2` to `float d = 5.2`.

Comment: Also, you don't need `typeof`. `sizeof(d)` will do just fine.

Comment: in addition to what @user3386109 depending on the endianess of the processor architecture you're using you might need to read the octets back to front,

Comment: Jes i got it using float. But im confused about 64 bit. In my example using double are 64 bits, am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit pattern you show, `0 10000001 01001100110011001100110`, is for an IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point representation, often used for `float`. You request the representation of a `double`, which often uses IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary.

The bytes you show, `cdcc cccc cccc 1440`, are a representation of approximately 5.2, in a little-endian order. In the high-value byte, the first bit, in position `0x80`, is zero. It is the sign bit, and zero means positive. The next seven bits, `0x40`, and the four bytes from the next byte, the `1` of `0x14`, are the exponent. Together, they are `0x401`. The exponent is biased by `0x3ff`. So, with an exponent encoded as `0x401`, the actual exponent is 2, meaning 2<sup>2</sup>.

The remaining bits encode the trailing bits of the significand. They are `0x4cccccccccccd`. For normal numbers, the significand is put after a “radix point” (the general equivalent of a decimal point) with 1 before the point: 1.4cccccccccccd<sub>16</sub>. In decimal, that is approximately 1.3 (exactly 1.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125).

Together, the value is + 2<sup>2</sup> • 1.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125 = 5.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how the 32-bit float specifically relates to the 64-bit float you can see the elements of the sign-bit, mantissa and exponent match up.

```
//Your double in little endian
11001101 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 00010100 01000000    

//for better readability in big endian
01000000 00010100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001101 

//the 32-bit float from the answer you linked
01000000 10100110 01100110 01100110

//1 bit sign  8/11-bit exponent   23/52-bit mantissa
0             10000000 001      01001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 1101
0             10000001          01001100 11001100 1100110
```

Why the value of the exponent and mantissa are the way the are is explained better in the answer you linked and elsewhere than I could do from the top of my head