# Easiest way to convert floating point of IEEE 754 to hexadecimal

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Can someone explain the step by step procedure to do the above?

Comment: Not only is it unclear what you are asking, I **think** a recently posted question asks something very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947861/32-bit-ieee-754-single-precision-floating-point-to-hexadecimal . A class-mate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [32-bit IEEE 754 single precision floating point to hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947861/32-bit-ieee-754-single-precision-floating-point-to-hexadecimal)

Answer (score 2):

The following is for IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even:

1. Start with input number *x*.
2. If *x* is 0, produce 0x00000000 (for 0) and stop.
3. Set *e* to 0.
4. Set *s* to 0 if 0 ≤ *x* or 1 if *x* < 0, and set *x* to |*x*|.
5. Repeat while 2 ≤ *x*: Divide *x* by 2 and add 1 to *e*.
6. Repeat while *x* < 1: Multiply *x* by 2 and subtract 1 from *e*.
7. Multiply *x* by 2<sup>23</sup>.
8. If *e* < −126, divide *x* by 2<sup>−126−*e*</sup> and set *e* to −126.
9. If the fraction part of *x* is less than ½, change it to 0.
10. If the fraction part of *x* is greater than ½, change it 0 and add 1 to *f*.
11. If the fraction part of *x* is ½, change it to 0. Then, if *x* is odd, add 1 to *x*.
12. Divide *x* by 2<sup>23</sup>.
13. If 2 ≤ *x*, divide *f* by 2 and add 1 to *e*.
14. If 127 < *e*:

    - If *s* is 1, produce 0xff800000 (for −∞) and stop.
    - Otherwise, produce 0x7f800000 (for +∞) and stop.
15. If 1 ≤ *x*:

    - Add 127 to *e* and subtract 1 from *x*.
    - Otherwise, set *e* to 0.
16. Produce *s*•2<sup>31</sup> + *e*•2<sup>23</sup> + *x*•2<sup>23</sup> in hexadecimal and stop.

The above is from memory and untested, so it should be double-checked.

Comment: If you're printing `0x7f800000` for +inf, is this supposed to be an algorithm for printing the binary32 bit-pattern in hex *without* type-punning it to integer?  So not a hex-float or something.

Comment: And BTW, I think you missed `-0.0` in your special cases at the top.  I guess move step 2. lower down until after decoding *s* from a compare result, and then if `x == 0.0` (rather than *is* 0) produce `s<<31`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The input is a real number, so −0 is 0.

Comment: @PeterCordes: In the same vein, the output is the IEEE-754 encoding for the result of converting the input to the nearest representable value. In one of the recent duplicates, the author said it was to prepare for a test, so I figure the input is a real number, not a `float` in C or something. I should have been more explicit about the input and output, but I should not have written this anyway—I have other things I need to be doing. I just could not resist putting it out there.

Comment: Oh, so you're not trying to preserve +-0.0 in your hex output?  I would have tried to preserve what you can (with functions like `signbit()`).  NaN payloads are obviously harder.  But ok if you're pretending the input is a real number, not an IEEE754 value like this question asks for, then that makes some sense.